# Formation of a hole in valence band

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, electrostatics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics

I have read that when an electron goes out from the valence band to reach the conduction band a hole is formed in the valence band.

A hole is seen as a positive charge e.

My question is why does an electron leaving creates a formation of a hole. Why doesn't the valence band stay as it is. What is the logic behind formation of a positive charge. Why is it that the removal of negative charge creates formation of a positive charge.Is it correct to say  that the positive charge was already there in the valence band before an electron came and sat there and hence the removal of electron exposed the positive charge back.

Answer (score 0):

The holes itself do not possess any charge it is the site at which there used to be an electron present but the electron leaves creating a potential at that position and when the near by electron comes in its place the hole moves to new position, they keep flowing on path discontinues unlike electron, the holes are said to be positive as they move in the direction of electric field, but we know it is actually the electrons moving in the other direction.

Comment: Its not that simple, if it was, you couldnt tell holes and electrons apart with the Hall effect. Holes are described as having a positive charge because they have a negative effective mass and its easier to think of positive charges than negative masses.

Comment: @Matt I was ignorant on this, we have not been taught about this till now thank you!!!